# Trying to stagger javascript notification based on random time interval but set frequency

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been spinning in a circle here. I'm trying to create a 'fomo/social proof' effect on a page, where a notification will slide in, then slide out. I want this notification to happen five times on the page and stop, but they are displayed with a random gap of time.

I'm trying to use setTimeout, but it seems they all happen sequentially without the gap of time. Looking at console, I see the duration and they have different values but are set initially, so the notifications are stacked instead of staggered.

I'm trying to do the following:

1. 5 seconds -> notification slides open. waits 7 seconds. notification slides away.
   Some random seconds
2. notification slides open. waits 7 second. notification slides away.
   Some random seconds
3. notification slides open. waits 7 second. notification slides away.
   Some random seconds
4. notification slides open. waits 7 second. notification slides away.
   Some random seconds
5. notification slides open. waits 7 second. notification slides away.
   Stops

   ```
   <script>
    $(function() {

        var counterVal = 0;

        doFomoSequence(counterVal);

        function doFomoSequence(counterVal){
            var secVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
            //secVal = 3000;
            setTimeout(doFomo(secVal), 5000);
            counterVal++;
            if(counterVal <= 5){
                doFomoSequence(counterVal);
            }


        }

        function doFomo(secVal){
            console.log(secVal);
            setTimeout( slideIn, secVal );
            setTimeout( slideOut, secVal + 7000 );
        }

        function slideIn(){
            $('#notification').animate({left: 20}, 'slow');
        }
        function slideOut(){
            $('#notification').animate({left: -400}, 'slow');
        }
    });
   ```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First argument to the `setTimeout` call should be a function declaration. In your case however, you are calling the function, which triggers the call immediately instead of having to wait. I would refactor to something like:

```js
function doFomoSequence(counterVal){
  var secVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
  //secVal = 3000;
  setTimeout(() => doFomo(secVal), 5000);
  counterVal++;
  if(counterVal <= 5){
     doFomoSequence(counterVal);
  }

}
```

You can checkout the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tobey_olinya/ad8cw24y)

Comment: That fiddle does
"got here"
"got here immediately"
"got here"

on load. I would want those to be spaced out.

Basically.
1. 5 seconds -> notification slides open. waits 7 seconds. notification slides away.
Some random seconds
2. notification slides open. waits 7 second. notification slides away.
Some random seconds
3. notification slides open. waits 7 second. notification slides away.
Some random seconds
4. notification slides open. waits 7 second. notification slides away.
Some random seconds
5. notification slides open. waits 7 second. notification slides away.
Stops

Comment: Realized I didn't include the updated link to the fiddle. Check again

Comment: Thank you! That's much closer. Is there a way to get the setTimeout 5000 ms to be random? I can get one random value and it sticks with that for every iteration. But I want every doFomoSequence to have a different time value. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can I see the code for that? I'm curious as to why that wouldn't work as expected